# Do I risk damaging my camera if I use an aftermarket AC adapter?

Tags: canon-50d, power-supply

I am looking at AC adapters for my Canon 50d. The Canon original is several times as expensive as some of the aftermarket options that I have found. Do I run any significant risk of damaging my camera if I use an Aftermarket Ac Adapter?

Comment: This should be an interesting read for you: [Should I buy an original manufacturer battery, or is a generic brand OK?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/should-i-buy-an-original-manufacturer-battery-or-is-a-generic-brand-ok)

Comment: "any risk" is too subjective to be a good SE topic. All of life is a risk. There is a non-zero risk of damage from Canon branded stuff, let alone nameless clones.

Are you really able to objectively evaluate the risk? Do you expect us to evaluate it for you?

Comment: Similar related question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/can-i-safely-use-my-camera-with-a-external-power-supply (not sure if considered an exact duplicate though)

Comment: @PatFarrell I should clarify. I am wondering if there is any significant risk. I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the proper voltage and current are provided, there shouldn't be any issues.  The thing that may be missing however is quality.  There are a number of different ways to adjust voltage and current and the cheapest adapters generally use cheaper methods of converting the power that are more prone to error or failure.

More expensive adapters tend to handle load more consistently and provide cleaner power, but it may very well not be necessary for your needs.  Additionally, there is still normally a decent mark up on the OEM adapters, so it's entirely possible that a third party adapter of equal quality could even be half the price, but it's always a dodgy game of figuring out which ones are good and which ones are not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and no.

Yes, you can damage the camera if you are using a low quality power adapter that for example delivers the wrong voltage.

No, you don't damage the camera just because a power adapter is not made by the same company as the camera.

One thing that you should check however, is how it affects the warranty of the camera. If using a third party power adapter voids the warranty, it's not really worth it.

Comment: In the US, [15 USC 2302(c)](http://uscode.house.gov/download/pls/15C50.txt) forbids voiding a warranty based solely on the use of a third-party accessory.  Somewhere else in that bit of law is language that says a warranty claim can be denied if it can be proven that the cause of a failure was the third-party accessory.

Answer (score 1):

You run a higher risk of harm to your equipment, your home or yourself. You may be lucky and get a decent quality power supply but the odds are against you if you buy a cheap unbranded supply.

See [crappy PSU analysis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T88ej64aXUM&list=UUcs0ZkP_as4PpHDhFcmCHyA&index=66)